# An equals method when the parameter is of type object

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and am having some trouble with casting/polymorphism concepts.

If I have the following method:

```
public boolean equals(Object x);
```

Where x could reference an Object of Class Y;

What's the best way to see if x equals y (a variable referencing an obj of Class Y) ? I understand downcasting e.g. (Y) x is bad?

Comment: Check if Object x is `instanceof` Class y, and if it is, then cast it to Class y.

Answer (score 3):

Downcasting is the norm in `Object.equals`. Before downcasting, check that `x` is indeed a compliant object with `x instanceof Y`; to ensure the symmetry of `equals`, a check `x.getClass() == this.getClass()` will be necessary at times.

If `x` is not an instance of your class, you immediately return `false`.

Comment: "a more correct check", well, AFAIK the experts are not clear on this. AFAIK, Joshua Bloch is recommending "instanceof" (in his book "Effective Java") and I think I read that Angelika Langer recommends "x.getClass() == this.getClass()" (not sure about that).

Comment: @puce Josh's argument is quite opinionated and phylosophical (invoking the Liskov substitition principle). He just dismisses the whole thing with "There is no way to extend a class and add a value component while preserving the `equals` contract". Well, it isn't *in general*, but what if it is *in particular*?

Answer (score 1):

Downcasting is not bad if you firstly perform the following checks:

1. Check for null --> `x != null`
2. Compare classes at runtime --> `getClass().equals(x.getClass())`

Then you can downcast `x` as the class of `this`, and perform specific comparisons.

Prior to your `null` check, you may also want to compare references of `this` and `x`.

If the references are equal, you don't need to perform any other comparison.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks, edited my answer - will re-edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on your interpretation of equality. That's why the equals operator can be overridden.

Just do `x.equals(y)` and do the interpretation of equality by overriding the equals method.

One template method for this is to do:

```
public boolean equals(Object x) {
  if (this == x)
    return true;
  if (x == null || this.getClass() != x.getClass())
    return false;
  // Compare attributes as needed here
}
```

Of course you should check if `x != null` before, if there are chances it is `null`.